# Find the first key bigger than X on Binary Search Tree

Tags: c, algorithm, binary-search-tree

> The successor of an element in a BST is the element's successor in the
>   sorted order determined by the inorder traversal. Finding the
>   successor when each node has a pointer to its parent node is presented
>   in CLRS's algorithm textbook (Introduction to Algorithms by MIT
>   press).

Is there a way to find the first value that is bigger than X without `parent` in the struct? Like:

```
typedef struct tree tree;
struct tree{
   int value;
   tree *left;
   tree *right;
};

//Function:  

tree *find_first_bigger(tree *t, int x){}
```

I  tried working with:

```
tree *find_first_bigger(tree *t, int x){
   if(t == NULL)
      return NULL;

   if((*t)->value > x)
      find_first_bigger((*t)->left, x);

   else if((*t)->value < x)
      find_first_bigger((*t)->right), x);
   else if((*t)->value == x){
      if((*t)->right != NULL) 
         return tree_first_bigger((*t)->right);
      else
         return tree;
   }
}
```

With this example(it's using letter but there its not a problem), if I try to search the first bigger than `N`(It should return me `O`) but it returns me `N`.

[image: Search Binary Tree]

Comment: I think you should put base case (if the current node is null) for that recursive function in order to stop if there is no bigger key than X in the tree. Also you should check if you found the key and return it.

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro Don't worry about the downvote, My solution is 100% correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have done 90% of the job.Allow me to do the remaining 10%.

Since t is a pointer to structure you should use **t->left** instead of **(*t)->left** and same applies while accessing **right** and **value** fields of the struct.

Now, Just modify your function as:

**Add this as first line of your function**

```
static tree* PTR=NULL;
```

**Modify the second if condition as**:

```
if(t->value > x)
 {
     PTR=t;
     find_first_bigger(t->left, x);
 }
```

**Modify the second else if condition as:**

```
else if(t->value == x)
{
  if(t->right != NULL)
     {
         t=t->right;
         while(t->left!=NULL)
            t=t->left;
         return t;
     }
  else return PTR;
}
```

**Hence the correct function is**

```
tree *find_first_bigger(tree *t, int x)
{
   static tree* PTR=NULL;
   if(t == NULL)
      return NULL;
   if(t->value > x)
     {
         PTR=t;
         find_first_bigger(t->left, x);
     }
   else if(t->value < x)
       find_first_bigger(t->right, x);
   else if(t->value == x)
    {
      if(t->right != NULL)
         {
             t=t->right;
             while(t->left!=NULL)
                t=t->left;
             return t;
         }
      else return PTR;
   }
}
```

In the main function if pointer returned is NULL, this means that :**the key itself is the largest key.** Feel free for any queries.

Comment: My solution works correct in all test cases still downvote? Also I have provided minimum modification of original code.

Comment: Man, you are my hero ! I could not make it work omg. Looking at your code, I imagine that the trick here was the static value, am I right ? Could you just explain to me what was that I could not see to make it work ? By the way, your code are clean, beautiful and works perfect !! Thank you very much Dante!

Comment: Dante. One other thing I could not understand. When I call recursively the function, the line `static tree* ptr = NULL` does not reset its value. Could you explain please?

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro static variables are meant for such purposes. Values of static variables are initialized only once and their life time equals the life time of the program unlike non-static variables which live no longer than the execution of function.

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro If you ever want a variable that should initialize itself at a particular point and never again and also should remember its value from previous function calls, remember the magical static variables, they are very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but I think it should work. Let me know if it is wrong.
//c++ 11

```
 #include<iostream>
 using namespace std;
 struct BSTNode{
     int val;
     BSTNode* left;
     BSTNode* right;
 };


 int FindJustLarger(BSTNode*& node, int token, int sofarlarge){
    // for invalid inputs it will return intial value of sofarlarge
    // By invalid input I mean token > largest value in BST
    if(node == nullptr)
        return sofarlarge;

    else if(node->val > token){
        sofarlarge = node->val;
        return FindJustLarger(node->left, token, sofarlarge);}

    else
        return FindJustLarger(node->right, token, sofarlarge);}

int main(){
    BSTNode* head = new BSTNode{5, nullptr, nullptr};
    FindJustLarger(head, 5, NULL);
    delete head;
    return 0;}
```

Answer (score -1):

Some changes you can do in your code:

- You have to return the values from the recursive calls
- If the value is not found, return `NULL`. This means returning `NULL` if `t->right == NULL` on the last `if`.
- When going to the left, if the value is not found there, the answer must be the node itself. In the case of `N`, it is the last node where we turn left: `O`. If it were `P`, the answer would be `T` itself.

After all those changes, the code should look like this:

```
tree *find_first_bigger(tree *t, int x){
   if(t == NULL)
      return NULL;

   if(t->value > x) {
      tree *answer = find_first_bigger(t->left, x);
      if (answer != NULL) 
          return answer;
      return t;
   } else if(t->value < x) {
      return find_first_bigger(t->right, x);
   } else if(t->value == x) {
      if (t->right != NULL)
          return tree_first_bigger(t->right);
      return NULL;
   }
}
```

You can find the entire code I used to test [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/juanplopes/386557a11ad616548173).

Answer (score -1):

In your question, you seemed to indicate that you want to find out InOrderSuccessor() of the the given value 'x'.

If 'x' does not necessarily exist in the tree, we need to change the algorithm. Given the example you provided and the problem statement, here is code for finding the next element in a BST.

The key cases are :

- No greater element exists, because 'x' is the biggest.
- 'x' has a right child ?
- YES: get left-most child of x's right sub-tree.
- NO : return parent.

Key observation is that we don't update the parent pointer, whenever we go right in the tree.

```
  tree *ptr = root;
  tree *prnt = NULL;
  while (ptr != NULL) {
      if (x == ptr->key) {
          if (ptr->right != NULL) {
              return GetLeftMostChild(ptr->right);
          } else {
              return prnt;
          }
      } else if (x > ptr->key) {
          ptr = ptr->right;
      } else {
          prnt = ptr;
          ptr = ptr->left;
      }
  }
```

Here is the definition for leftMostChild()

```
tree *GetLeftMostChild(tree *n) {
    tree *ptr = n;
    while (ptr->left != NULL) {
        ptr = ptr->left;
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

Comment: I believe you can simply replace your entire `if (prnt != NULL)` block with `return prnt` (**Note:** OP has requested the return of a pointer and not the next `int` itself).  The check for `if (prnt != NULL)` is not necessary, because there is either a pointer value or you will `return NULL` based on your initialization of `tree *prnt = NULL;` (which is what will occur if you `break` as the return for the function is `return prnt;`)

Comment: That makes more sense. The only other nit is `return GetLeftMostChild(ptr->right)->key;` should be `return GetLeftMostChild(ptr->right);` in order to return the node instead of the value. The reason you don't want to return the value is in the event `if (x == ptr->key)` and `if (ptr->right == NULL)`, you segfault when you `break` and attempt to `return prnt->key;` (which is an attempt to dereference a `NULL` pointer)